# What's the advantage of building extensions inplace when installing scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to install the development version of scikit-learn. Here is the statement about it in the [document](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#contributing-code):

> If you run the development version, it is cumbersome to reinstall the package each time you update the sources. It is thus preferred that you add the scikit-learn directory to your `PYTHONPATH` and build the extension in place:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

I cannot quite understand this instruction. As far as I know, the `--inplace` option is to put the built files into the same directory as the pure python modules. How does it relate to avoiding reinstalling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that you have your scikit-learn distribution in scikit-learn dir

```
git clone https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git
cd scikit-learn
```

Your citation about reinstalling means that when you run:

```
python setup.py install
```

Install script builds pyx files, runs tests and copies all files into some system folder of OS. And let's imagine that you want to fix some bug in scikit-learn package, or add new functionality. How would you do this? Project in scikit-learn doesn't have any influence on that files which were installed by install script into some location, thus if you change these files in scikit-learn folder and import sklearn from terminal - you will import unchanged files (Because you import files not from that scikit-learn dir, but from some OS dir).

If you want to import sklearn with recently modified sources - you can achieve it in 3 ways:

1. run `python setup.py install` after each modification of scikit-learn library files, but it's cumbersome
2. modify library files in your OS dir (dir where scikit-learn gets installed), but it often requires administrator rights and if you break it - you break library which may be used by another scripts in your system.
3. Build it in place as you mentioned in question, and after that you can enter into scikit-learn sources folder and run `import sklearn`, it will import library from current folder, with any modifications that you've made. (But you cannot do such import without running `build_ext --inplace` previously)

[Look also 'develop' mode](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#develop-deploy-the-project-source-in-development-mode)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed introduction. So basically building in-place means that we can run `build_ext --inplace` instead of `install` after each modification, save a copying process, and if we just modify some pure python modules, then the modification will be effective immediately without any additional building or installing. Is my understanding right?

Comment: @Bor, yes, it will be available for testing immediately, after reimport of that module from some folder (in which you've built that module inplace).

Also, it works not only with sklearn.

Comment: Thank you, @Olologin. Btw, what's the difference between "add the scikit-learn dir to `PYTHONPATH` and run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`" and "run `python setup.py develop`"? Is there any essential difference? Which one do you prefer as an experienced contributor?

Comment: Hmm, honestly i've never used develop mode before. But look here https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#develop-deploy-the-project-source-in-development-mode
I think that they are similar, but `develop` uses `build_ext -i` implicitly, and automatically creates links from staging area to your development dir + automatically checks for dependencies. At least documentation states so.